# Не работает BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver

Пытаюсь сделать так, что бы `BroadcastReceiver` обновлял время в приложении согласно системному. Написал вот такой код, но ничего не меняется. В чем ошибка?

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            timeView.setText(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        }
    };
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` срабатывает при изменении времени пользователем.
Для отлова изменения времени от системы используйте `Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK`

[Источник](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)